# Processing data from a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rest, express

I have a frontend (user interface) and a database in place. They are connected via a REST API. The frontend is implemented in Angular, the database is a MariaDB and the API was implemented in Express. In the API all my Get/Post/Put/Delete Methods are defined and I am capable of writing and reading from/into the database.
What do I need to do if I have data that does not explicitly exist in the database but has to be calculated instead of the database data? Where do I implement this logic? I don't want to add it to my frontend or my database so it obviously has to be in the API (or somewhere in between). Is there a common standard of how it is handled?
In addition, it has to be said that the calculated data should be displayed in the frontend but does not have to be stored in the database.

Comment: You mean you want to show A+B+C on front end but you only have B and C in your DB and you don't wan to store A either on front end or on back end? So, where does A comes from? ^-^

Comment: I think you are confusing API with your web application. An API is an application programming interface, so it only defines contracts, not implementation. What you want is the business logic layer. I think it would be interesting to look into the basics of software architecture. that's usually where datamanipulation is done, but it happens on a shallow level also in the ui. i would not worry about that too much. Changing a single property in the UI is no problem, but creating entire objects, or doing complex manipulations is usually the responsability of the business logic.

Comment: So what i did in express.js is the business logic layer that connects the frontend to the database. Can i add my calcuations in there? @Mridul i want to store A, B and C in the database but not A+B+C, that should only be displayed in the frontend

Comment: If you have all the required parameters in your back end then it depends entirely on your front end part whether to A+B+C or to A-B-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest rule is: **be consistent**.

I would personally opt to implement that login in the Express API simply because then more clients could share that easily. A simple case is if you have users with `firstName` and `lastName` in your database, but you also want another handy field `name` which contact firstName and lastName because you use it really often. If you do that at the API level, every client could benefit from it.

This is just an example but the main point is consistency: don't mix logic like that between frontend and backend because then is way less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Send your values to the server through the REST API(post or get method). Write the business logic there itself(controller) and return the value. you don't want to process these data's with your DB